# Can't 'docker pull' from CoreOS to an insecure local Docker repository

Tags: ssl, docker, coreos

I have followed these instructions to no avail:

```
#cloud-config

coreos:

units:
  - name: docker.service
    drop-ins:
      - name: 50-insecure-registry.conf
        content: |
          [Service]
          Environment='DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry="10.0.1.0/24"'
```

If I try to pull from an HTTP docker repository end-point, it keeps insisting on attempting a TLS handshake on the non-SSL port 80. eg:

```
coreos $ docker pull mylaptop:8080/supercool/container
```

What gives? I have double-checked that the `docker.service.d` folder contains the file `50-insecure-registry.conf`, but it still keeps insisting on using SSL.

How do I pull from a local insecure container from CoreOS?

Comment: Code blocks need _four_ leading spaces, but the post had only two. There is a button on the editor `{}` which will insert them for you, after selecting the text to which you want it to apply.